# Round up price value in float

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In my product.tpl Prestashop file, I have this code:

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
```

problem :
in the UI, I'm getting 2 different prices:

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="116.592863">117‎</span>
```

I want that the "content" price will be like the actual price.

How to round the price in the "content", in order to get the same price as in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicate the value :)

```
content="{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
```